# How to update table view cells' textView tags without calling tableView.reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, callback, textview

I have a tableView controller that utilizes custom cells with textViews. Currently, I have a callback function so that whenever a user hits return while editing the textView, a new cell is inserted into the tableView and it becomes the first responder. In order to do this, whenever the user hits return I store the textView's tag + 1 in a variable called cellCreatedWithReturn so the tableView knows where to insert the cell and which cell to make first responder. The problem is that before the tableView reloads, there ends up being duplicate textView tags. If there's already a textView with a tag of 5 and I hit return while editing the textView with tag of 4, it creates another cell with a textView tag of 5. Now the first tag of 5 is located at row 6, but since it's tagged as 5, hitting return on it causes a cell to be inserted at row 6 instead of at row 7. I've tried changing the callback to just use the indexPath.row instead of the cellCreatedWithReturn variable, but that causes the new cell to always be inserted as the last cell in the tableView. I don't want to call tableView.reloadData() because that will cause the keyboard to be lowered and then raised back up right away when the first responder is reassigned, which doesn't look good. I need for the keyboard to stay raised.

Here is my shouldChangeTextIn where the callback is called:

```
var cellCreatedWithReturn: Int?
var returnKeyCallback: (()->())?

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if(text == "\n") {
        cellCreatedWithReturn = textView.tag + 1
        print(cellCreatedWithReturn!)
        returnKeyCallback?()
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

And the callback function in cellForRowAt:

```
self.returnKeyCallback = { [weak self] in
    if let self = self {
        let newRow = self.cellCreatedWithReturn! - 1
        // this is -1 because cell 0 is not included in the same data source
        do {
            try self.realm.write {
                self.song.lyrics.insert(LyricLine(), at: newRow)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error when inserting new lyric line to song in Realm when return pressed")
        }
        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: self.cellCreatedWithReturn!, section: 0)
        print(newIndexPath.row)
        self.tableView.performBatchUpdates({
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
        }, completion: { b in
            guard let c = tableView.cellForRow(at: newIndexPath) as? newNoteTableViewCell else { return }
            c.lyricsField.becomeFirstResponder()
            c.lyricsField.tag = self.cellCreatedWithReturn!
            if indexPath.row > newIndexPath.row {
                cell.lyricsField.tag += 1
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of storing the row information in the tag of the textview, you could get the index path of the currently selected cell, then add a new cell below that, and select that new cell (and the text field inside it)

Comment: @AndreasOetjen The problem I'm having with that approach is that tapping a cell to edit its textView does not select the cell.

Comment: I know. You need to (programatically) select the cell that holds the textView.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen I see. And how would that be done in this situation? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to disable user interaction on the UITextView first, then enable it programmatically when the cell is selected and assign the first responder in the next line.